# Estimation of partitioning error in next-generation sequencing experiments

Tags: biostatistics, sequence-analysis, partitioning

[Edited: explanation of the partitioning error]

I would like to estimate how the initial number of molecules (or the level of gene expression) affects reproducibility between technical replicates of my sequencing experiment (one vial - one experiment).

Simplifying, we have $X$ different genes with $N_x$ RNA molecules for each gene. We take the genes one by one and partition $N_x$ molecules between $R$ identical vials. We assume that each vial has the same probability. Given the number of molecules ($N_x$), what is the expected partitioning error.

Partitioning error: If $r_1, r_2, ... , r_n$ are the number of molecules within each vial after partitioning, partitioning error is a spread of $r_1, r_2, ... , r_n$

Comment: Sorry, im not really well versed in genetics, Could you define what partitioning error means for this problem.

Comment: I added an explanation.

Comment: spread isn't a well defined statistical term. Do you mean variance? The ratio of correct to incorrect partitionings?

Comment: I am sorry, I am quite new to the field. I mean variance, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I believe the way we can look at your problem with a multinomial distribution. Like the binomial models the sorting of N balls into 2 containers, the multinomial models the sorting of N balls into m containers. So in this case, take a gene (call it gene1), this gene has N_1 molecules. If you have an equal probability of these molecules ending up in each of the R vials, then on average, you will get $N_1 /R$ molecules in each vial. Now, since we hope that the partitioning acts the same for each gene, this means that we now have a probability model for this situation, ie independence between genes, the joint distribution is now the product of multinomials. This means that if $y_{ij}$ represents the number of molecules of gene i in vial j, we have the probaiblity model:
$$f(y_{11} .... y_{I,J}) = \prod_{i=1}^I \prod_{j=1}^J Multinomial(N_i, (1/2, ... 1/2)) =\prod_{i=1}^I \prod_{j=1}^J \frac{N_x}{y_{ij}!} p_{ij}^{y_{ij}} $$
Great, we now have a statistical model for this phenomenon. Now we can compute the variance. When we deal with just one gene, we have a multinomial $(y_{1,i}, ... y_{I,i}) \sim $Multinomial(N_i, (1/2, ... 1/2), so you can get right from the wiki that:
$$Var(Y_i) = n_i p_i (1-p_i) = N_i (1/2)^2 = 4 N_i$$
$$Cov(Y_i,Y_j) = -n_i p_i p_j =  -\frac{N_i}{4} $$
Now when we upgrade to the multiple gene situation, since we are assuming independnece between genes, this becomes the product-multinomial distribution. The variance matrix of the product-multinomial would give you what you are looking for.